# Clarification of a logical deduction example

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I would like to ask for some clarification on an assignment of logical deduction. Specifically, the question is *Which of the following are logically correct deductions?* and below is an example:

> If an International Weapons Limitation Agreement is signed, or
> the United Nations approve a disarmament plan, then shares in
> the arms industry will slump. But armament shares will not slump,
> so an International Weapons Limitation Agreement will not be
> signed.

Presumably, the above statements can be converted accordingly:

**P** - International Weapons Limitation Agreement is signed

**Q** - the United Nations approve a disarmament plan

**R** - shares in the arms industry will slump

The first statement (*If an International Weapons ... will slump*) then becomes $(P \lor Q) \Rightarrow R$ and the second one (*But armament shares ... so not be signed*) $\neg R \Rightarrow \neg P$.

Assuming that the first statement is true, it can only be true if $P, Q, R$ are respectively:

1. $t, t, t$
2. $t, f, t$
3. $f, t, t$
4. $f, f, t$
5. $f, f, f$

In all of the above cases of values of $P, Q, R$ also the second statement $\neg R \Rightarrow \neg P$ is true.

Does this then mean that the second statement is indeed a correct logical deduction from the first one? If yes, is it because a deduction has to be true whenever an original statement is true?

Comment: $A \implies B$ is logically equivalent to $(\neg B) \implies (\neg A).$  Further, $\neg(R \vee S)$ is logically equivalent to $[(\neg R) \wedge (\neg S)].$  Finally, you have that if the statement $[C \wedge D]$ is true, then the statement (for example) $[C]$ is true.  That is, $[C \wedge D] \implies [C].$  Also, $A \implies B$ is logically equivalent to $[(\neg A) \vee (B)].$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is not quite right. Instead of the conclusion being $\neg R \Rightarrow \neg P$, the $\neg R$ is actually stated as fact, i.e. $\neg R$ is a second premise. And, the conclusion is simply $\neg P$

But yes, this is a deductively valid argument. To quickly see this, note that if the IWLA does get signed, then given the first premise it is clear that arnament shares will slump ... but given that the second premise tells us that the shares don't slump, it cannot be true either that the IWLA gets signed.